# Opencart: error 404 in Simple Blog when enable Use SEO URLs

Tags: opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

Modelu : simple-blog

I have enable Use SEO URLs (Admin: Settings >> Server >> Use SEO URLs), if you click on blog page in frontend, get error 404.

Url : localhost/opencart/Establishing-Your-Brand-on-College-Campuses